# Camera in Minecraft PS4

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console

When I play Minecraft on PS4, I have to press the left button to change Camera View. Would it be possible to make it so that all I have to do is rotate the left stick around the character to change the Camera View?

Answer (score 2):

As shown in this video this is what third person view is meant to do, this cannot be adjusted in any way in any of the settings.